# Change specific character in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, console, character, edit

After searching the internet quite a bit, I haven't found any simple solution for my kind of problem.

**Is it possible to change a specific character in the terminal in python?**

For example, lets say i have a `40 x 40` matrix filled with spaces and there is one dot in the middle. is it possible to ***move*** the dot (i.e. delete it and put it somewhere else) **without** clearing the whole terminal and loading the new state of the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for `curses`

- [Tutorial: Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html)
- [Documentation: Terminal handling for character-cell display](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **No**. 
If you are trying to make a game, you should use a library or engine that will reload the canvas some n times per second, but you can`t reload a terminal output.

Comment: I am trying to make a game. But I do want to do that without using PyGame or some other engine. Are you saying that the only option i've got to 'move' the player is to clear the whole screen and print the whole map again?

Comment: @pystudent yes. That's actually how games are made. You can't move things, you just reload their new position at a very high speed (usually 30 or 60 times (frames) per second - thats where expressions like 30fps and 60fps come from)

Comment: Can I ask why you would avoid using a library written specifcally for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @IanAuld I'm trying to do this with the least amount of libraries, but also it sounds like it should be possible to create a text based game without any graphics. If that's a real issue I'll consider using pyGame anyway. (or another library if you have a better one to suggest)

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Don't avoid using a library just for the sake of not using a library.